# Как удалить определённое количество символов из строки в Ruby?

Tags: строки, ruby

Я хочу сделать программу, которая будет отрезать 16 символов с конца названия каждого файла в директории. Должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
Dir.glob("Videos/*.mp4") {|file|
    puts file.cut[-16]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается следующим кодом:

```
Dir.glob("Videos/*.mp4") {|file|
    puts file[0...-16]
}
```